# How can I fix subs() not working in my code?

Tags: python, sympy

I'm trying to sub the symbol 't' with 'p' which is an array of numbers, but when I print qsub, it shows that the .subs() command didn't work.

```
from sympy import *
import numpy as np

t = Symbol('t')

q = Matrix([(10*cos(t), 10*sin(t), 10*(10-(t/10)))])
v = diff(q, t)
a = diff(q, t, 2)
j = diff(q, t, 3)

p = np.linspace(0, 100, 1000)
qsub = q.subs(t, p)
qsub
```

[10cos(t), 10sin(t), 100−t]

Comment: `lambdify(t, q)(p)`

Answer (score 0):

or if you just want to print out the evaluation:

```
for pt in p:
    print(q.subs(t,pt))
```